# How to add a bitmap to a specific album in the gallery?

Tags: java, c#, xamarin, bitmap, gallery

I have tried many ways yet none of them works. I want to create a specific album and to save bitmap into JPEGs in there.

I use Xamarin. What shall I do?

Comment: try https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a demo about it.

I put a picture in resource folder, then i will read it to bitmap

```
 btnSelectImage = (Button)FindViewById(Resource.Id.btnSelectImage);
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeResource(this.ApplicationContext.Resources , Resource.Drawable.splashlogo);
        btnSelectImage.Click += (o, e) =>
        {
            saveImageToGally(bitmap, this);
        };
```

then send it to the specific album in the gallery.

[image]

There is code.

```
public void saveImageToGally(Bitmap finalBitmap,Context context)
    {
        //create a directory called MyCamera
        string root = Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DirectoryDcim).ToString() + "/MyCamera/";

       //create the Directory
        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(root);

        File myDir = new File(root);
        myDir.Mkdir();
        //Image name
        string fname = "Image-" + "Image1" + ".png";
        File file = new File(myDir, fname);
        Log.Error("FilePath", file.AbsolutePath);

        if (file.Exists()) file.Delete();
        Log.Error("FilePath", root + fname);
        //total path
        string path = root + fname;

        try
        {


            var fs = new System.IO.FileStream(path, System.IO.FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
            if (fs != null)
            {
                finalBitmap.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Png, 90, fs);
                fs.Close();
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.PrintStackTrace();

        }

        MediaScannerConnection.ScanFile(context, new string[] { file.Path }, new string[] { "image/jpeg" }, null);

    }
```

Please do not forget to add following permission.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Please note that you should grant the external storage permissions during the runtime since they are critical permissions!

You can read more [here](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting).

Comment: That actually solved my problem with the other answer.. thanks!